# Python Requests package: Handling xml response

Tags: python, xml, httprequest, python-requests

I like very much the `requests` package and its comfortable way to handle JSON responses.

Unfortunately, I did not understand if I can also process XML responses. Has anybody experience how to handle XML responses with the `requests` package? Is it necessary to include another package for the XML decoding?

Comment: In case you use [pydantic](https://pypi.org/project/pydantic/), you can rely on [pydantic-xml](https://github.com/dapper91/pydantic-xml) to transform your XML data into a pydantic schema

Answer (score 240):

`requests` does not handle parsing XML responses, no. XML responses are much more complex in nature than JSON responses, how you'd serialize XML data into Python structures is not nearly as straightforward.

Python comes with built-in XML parsers. I recommend you use the [ElementTree API](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html):

```py
import requests
from xml.etree import ElementTree

response = requests.get(url)

tree = ElementTree.fromstring(response.content)
```

or, if the response is particularly large, use an incremental approach:

```py
response = requests.get(url, stream=True)

# if the server sent a Gzip or Deflate compressed response, decompress
# as we read the raw stream:
response.raw.decode_content = True

events = ElementTree.iterparse(response.raw)

for event, elem in events:
    # do something with `elem`
```

The external [lxml project](https://lxml.de/index.html) builds on the same API to give you more features and power still.

Comment: I always used lxml, didn't know this already exists in python built-in.

Answer (score 35):

A much simpler way is to convert the XML into a `dict` using the [xmltodict](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict) package

```
response = requests.get('http://blabla.com')
dict_data = xmltodict.parse(response.content)
```

Now, `dict_data` it's just a Python dictionary.

You can install it with pip: `pip install xmltodict`

Comment: When I try to use this I get "ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 2".     

This is the beginning of the xml text:
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="SettlementSummary.xsl"?>

Comment: Hi @otterdog2000, I think your question lie outside the scope of this issue, you should open another one