# Efficient web page scraping with Python/Requests/BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, splinter

I am trying to grab information from the Chicago Transit Authority [bustracker](http://www.ctabustracker.com/bustime/eta/eta.jsp?id=15475) website.  In particular, I would like to quickly output the arrival ETAs for the top two buses.  I can do this rather easily with Splinter; however I am running this script on a headless Raspberry Pi model B and Splinter plus pyvirtualdisplay results in a significant amount of overhead.

Something along the lines of

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'http://www.ctabustracker.com/bustime/eta/eta.jsp?id=15475'
r = requests.get(url)
s = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')
```

does not do the trick.  All of the data fields are empty (well, have &nbsp).  For example,  when the page looks like this:

[image]

This code snippet `s.find(id='time1').text` gives me `u'\xa0'` instead of "12 MINUTES" when I perform the analogous search with Splinter.

I'm not wedded to BeautifulSoup/requests; I just want something that doesn't require the overhead of Splinter/pyvirtualdisplay since the project requires that I obtain a short list of strings (e.g. for the image above, `[['9','104th/Vincennes','1158','12 MINUTES'],['9','95th','1300','13 MINUTES']]`) and then exits.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**The bad news**

So the bad news is the page you are trying to scrape is rendered via Javascript. Whilst tools like Splinter, Selenium, PhantomJS can render this for you and give you the output to easily scrape, Python + Requests + BeautifulSoup don't give you this out of the box.

**The good news**

The data pulled in from the Javascript has to come from somewhere, and usually this will come in an easier to parse format (as it's designed to be read by machines).

In this case your example loads [this XML](http://www.ctabustracker.com/bustime/eta/getStopPredictionsETA.jsp?route=all&stop=15475&key=0.3003391435305782).

Now with an XML response it's not as nice as JSON so I'd recommend reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18308594/1401034) about integrating with the requests library. But it will be a *lot* more lightweight than Splinter.

Comment: Excellent catch.  I waded through the javascript on the page but could not identify where the dynamic information was coming from.  I appreciate the XML reference.