# ElementTree.iterparse with streamed and cached request throws ParseError

Tags: python, caching, streaming, python-requests, elementtree

I have a Flask app that retrieves an XML document from a url and processes it. I'm using requests_cache with redis to avoid extra requests and ElementTree.iterparse to iterate over the streamed content. Here's an example of my code (same result occurs from both the development server and the interactive interpreter):

```
>>> import requests, requests_cache
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
>>> requests_cache.install_cache('test', backend='redis', expire_after=300)
>>> url = 'http://myanimelist.net/malappinfo.php?u=doomcat55&status=all&type=anime'
>>> response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
>>> for event, node in ET.iterparse(response.raw):
...     print(node.tag)
```

Running the above code once throws a ParseError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1301, in __next__
    self._root = self._parser._close_and_return_root()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1236, in _close_and_return_root
    root = self._parser.close()
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: no element found: line 1, column 0
```

However, running the exact same code again before the cache expires actually prints the expected result! How come the XML parsing fails the first time only, and how can I fix it?

---

**Edit:**
If it's helpful, I've noticed that running the same code without the cache results in a different ParseError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1289, in __next__
    for event in self._parser.read_events():
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1272, in read_events
    raise event
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1230, in feed
    self._parser.feed(data)
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 0
```

Comment: Interesting, if you would do `ET.iterparse(StringIO(response.text))` instead, it would work all of the time, though I guess you have a reason to use `.raw` in this case.

Comment: @alecxe Hm, that seems to imply to me that the problem is caused because ET is trying to parse a document that hasn't fully loaded... I'm pretty sure it's possible to do this, though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18308529/python-requests-package-handling-xml-response

Comment: @alecxe, first run caching consumes the data, not caching means you are passing gzipped data which etree cannot parse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can tell you why it fails for both scenarios, for the latter it is  because the data is *gzipped* the first time you call raw, whatever happens when you read the second time then the data is decompressed:

If you print the lines:

```
for line in response.raw:
    print(line)
```

You see:

```
�=V���H�������mqn˫+i�������UȣT����F,�-§�ߓ+���G�o~�����7�C�M{�3D����೺C����ݣ�i�����SD�݌.N�&�HF�I�֎�9���J�ķ����s�*H�@$p�o���Ĕ�Y��v�����8}I,��`�cy�����gE�� �!��B�  &|(^���jo�?�^,���H���^~p��a���׫��j�

����a۱Yk<qba�RN6�����l�/�W����{/��߸�G

X�LxH��哫 .���g(�MQ ����Y�q��:&��>s�M�d4�v|��ܓ��k��A17�
```

And then decompressing:

```
import zlib
def decomp(raw):
    decompressor = zlib.decompressobj(zlib.MAX_WBITS | 16)
    for line in raw:
        yield decompressor.decompress(line)

for line in decomp(response.raw):
    print(line)
```

You see the decompression works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<myanimelist><myinfo><user_id>4731313</user_id><user_name>Doomcat55</user_name><user_watching>3</user_watching><user_completed>120</user_completed><user_onhold>8</user_onhold><user_dropped>41</user_dropped><user_plantowatch>2</user_plantowatch><user_days_spent_watching>27.83</user_days_spent_watching></myinfo><anime><series_animedb_id>64</series_animedb_id><series_title>Rozen Maiden</series_title><series_synonyms>; Rozen Maiden</series_synonyms><series_type>1</series_type><series_episodes>12</series_episodes><series_status>2</series_status><series_start>2004-10-08</series_start><series_end>2004-12-24</series_end><series_image>http://cdn.myanimelist.net/images/anime/2/15728.jpg</series_image>
..................................
```

Now after caching, if we read a few bytes:

```
response.raw.read(39)
```

You see we get decompressed data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Forgetting caching and passing the *response.raw* to iterparse gives:

```
    raise e
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 0
```

Because it cannot handle *gzipped* data.

Also using the following on the first run while caching:

```
for line in response.raw:
    print(line)
```

Gives me:

```
    ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

That is because the *caching* has consumed the data so there is in fact nothing there so not sure if using raw with caching is actually possible as the data is consumed and the file handle is closed.

If you use [*lxml.fromstringlist*](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree-module.html#fromstringlist):

```
import requests, requests_cache
import lxml.etree as et
requests_cache.install_cache()

def lazy(resp):
    for line in resp.iter_content():
        yield line

url = 'http://myanimelist.net/malappinfo.php?u=doomcat55&status=all&type=anime'

response = requests.get(url, stream=True)

for node in et.fromstringlist(lazy(response)):
    print(node)
```

Comment: Thanks! So on the first request, do you think it's possible to stream the response and decompress/parse it without loading the entire response at once?

Comment: You want to cache and iterate using the stream?

Comment: Yes. The XML can get quite large, so I'm trying to avoid having it all in memory at once.

Comment: Yeah, I'm actually trying it out atm.

Comment: @Noah, I added an example using iter_content,  bar you write the data yourself you won't be able to use raw, the issue is that behind the scenes on the first run the cache us being filled so there is nothing left by the time you parse, you would have to tee the output yourself which would not be too hard but it does not seem to be available as is

Comment: Thanks, though this seems to be slower than just downloading the file all at once (w/o streaming) and then using iterparse. You've definitely given me enough to work with though, I should be able to figure out a solution on my own.

Comment: Steaming will definitely be slower, like I said i don't think the raw caching works out of the box but it would only take a little bit of code to handle that, basically write the raw data and read in tee like fashion.