# How to correctly retrieve data from XML received from POST request

Tags: python, python-3.x, post, xml-parsing, python-requests

So I am writing a Python script in order to obtain data from XML that I get in response to an API request which was sent using `POST` and the [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library.

Currently I am using my request like so and getting a response back like:

```
req = requests.post(url + '/endpoint', headers = headers, params = {'search': searchQuery}, verify = False)
print(req.text)
```

This results in `req.text` giving a response to me of my XML which is structured like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xml" href="/static/atom.xsl"?>
<feed>
    <!-- Feed elements>
    <entry>
        <!-- Other Elements -->
        <content type="text/xml">
            <s:dict>
                <!-- Other keys. -->
                <s:key name="sid">DATA I WANT HERE</s:key>
                <!-- Other keys. -->
            </s:dict>
            <!-- Lots of other dicts here. -->
        </content>
    </entry>
    <! -- Other entries -->
</feed>
```

My goal is to obtain all the data from the `s:key` with `name` of `sid` and print that out. There are hundreds of entries per feed and in each there is only one `s:key` with a `sid` in it (it's a service identifier I need to obtain).

My issue is I'm not sure how to extract it, cause right now I'm trying to use [Element Tree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) like so, but it is not returning the results I want.

```
print(req.text)
results = ET.fromstring(req)
for job in results.findall('s:key'):
    print(job.get('name'))
```

I also tried:

```
for node in results.findall('s:key'):
    if node.attrib['name'] == "sid":
        print(node)
```

which also does not give me the info I want.

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it? I'm somewhat unfamiliar with Python and very new to XML parsing so I would appreciate some insights into this problem.

Addendum:

To add, currently it seems to just print out all the XML lines with `s:key` and an attribute of `name` in them which I do not want.

For example a sample output at the moment is:

```
<s:key name="a">74993868</s:key>
<s:key name="b">0</s:key>
<s:key name="c">date</s:key>
<s:key name="d">6000</s:key>
<s:key name="e">600</s:key>
<s:key name="f">text</s:key>
<s:key name="sid">data I actually want</s:key>
<!-- Etc -->
```

Comment: Did you check this question to see if it helps you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18308529/python-requests-package-handling-xml-response

Comment: @daniboy000 I double checked and also updated my question to better reflect the issue.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to use Regex:

Using the regex you will find the groups, like this [Regex](https://regex101.com/r/fTA1u4/1).

```py
>>> import re
>>> m = re.search(r'\<s\:\S+\sname=\"sid\"\>(.+)\<.+', string, re.MULTILINE)
>>> print(m.groups())
('DATA I WANT HERE',)
```

Comment: While this works, I only get the very first data set. i.e. It doesn't return any of the other matching items, even though when I dump to file and `CTRL+F` I can see at least 500 matching results.