# Convert XML to python dictionary

Tags: python, xml, api

I am sending a request to an API:

```
import requests as rq

resp_tf = rq.get("https://api.t....")
tf_text = resp_tf.text
```

Which prints:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<flowSegmentData version="traffic-service 4.0.011">
<frc>FRC0</frc>
<currentSpeed>78</currentSpeed>
<freeFlowSpeed>78</freeFlowSpeed>
<currentTravelTime>19</currentTravelTime>
<freeFlowTravelTime>19</freeFlowTravelTime>
<confidence>0.980000</confidence>
 <roadClosure>false</roadClosure>
<coordinates>
<coordinate>
  .....
```

Now how can I get the values of the tags for example "currentSpeed"

Comment: You could try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18308529/python-requests-package-handling-xml-response)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using the [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) module.

The code is self-explanatory:

- Search for the tag by its name using the [`find_all()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) method.
- Create a dictionary where the `key` is the name of the tag found, and the `value` is the text of the tag.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

xml = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<flowSegmentData version="traffic-service 4.0.011">
<frc>FRC0</frc>
<currentSpeed>78</currentSpeed>
<freeFlowSpeed>78</freeFlowSpeed>
<currentTravelTime>19</currentTravelTime>
<freeFlowTravelTime>19</freeFlowTravelTime>
<confidence>0.980000</confidence>
 <roadClosure>false</roadClosure>
<coordinates>
<coordinate>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, "html.parser")

print({tag.name: tag.text for tag in soup.find_all("currentspeed")})
```

Output:

```
{'currentspeed': '78'}
```

Comment: Sure, yes, thank you. BS is the easiest way !